# Spring-Boot URL shortener, "/**" mapping and custom 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hey awesome StackOverflow community,
I'm quite new to the world of Spring Boot and microservices. I'm developing an URL shortener, i made the logic and managed the storage with JPA and i've been able to manage the redirect with this controller:

```java
@GetMapping("/**")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> redirect(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String source = request.getRequestURI().toLowerCase();

        if (source.startsWith("/")) source = source.substring(1);

        ShortUrl shortUrl = shortUrlService.getShortUrlBySource(source);

        if (shortUrl == null) throw new ShortUrlNotFoundException(); // 404

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(URI.create(shortUrl.getDestination()));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.FOUND);
    }
```

I'd like to use a custom 404 page and to achieve that i've tried different things linke interceptors or variation of the previews method but nothing worked. I've only managed to display the browser default 404 page, the default whitelabel error page or a StackOverflowException due to the request looping between the previous method and the 404 static page.

Is there some kind guy that can help me with this tricky problem?
Thank you

Comment: Microservices should not have pages. Your rest endpoint will return 404 status code, and client should handle this.

Comment: I have already a full rest api to create, get and delete the "ShortURLs", but, since this will be part of a website, i want a user who wrote an invalid url to see a nice 404 error page

Comment: Assuming its a Java server, this mapping goes into web.xml `<error-page>` definition: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/web_xml.htm#WBAPP537

Comment: Right now i don't have a web.xml, i'd like to run it as a standalone application. Can the thing you suggested be done in this case?

Comment: If it is a web application, running in a Java Server, just create the web.xml. You talked about Spring boot, so it could be a Jetty server, IDK...

Comment: Reading online i found that in the newer versions of spring boot web.xml should be avoided and that i should use an ErrorController. Is that true?